# import module fail when using sudo

Tags: python

I would like to import pylibfreenect2, when I am in user mode, it work fine.

```
python3
>>> import pylibfreenect2
```

However, It fail import module in `sudo` and `sudo -E -H`

```
sudo python3 
>>> import pylibfreenect2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pylibfreenect2/__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from .libfreenect2 import *
ImportError: libfreenect2.so.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Because I need to use python2.7 sometimes, I cannot use PYTHONPATH in `~/.bashrc`.

Is there other method to solve? Thank you very much, My OS is ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage different Python versions and switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
sudo -E -H
```

Does not save the current HOME variable, when using -H you need to indicate the target user (cf. https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html). Try to use:

```
sudo -E -H -u ${your_user}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I try it, and still import fail

Comment: Can you print the sys.path under python when launched by user and by the sudo command ?